# Xcode localization: All strings are not translated

Tags: xcode, localization, localizable.strings

I've an iPhone app that i wanted to localize so i've added chinese localization. To do so I added Localizable.strings(chinese) to my app and i added the strings in it.

But a weird thing happens when I compile, only half or maybe even less of the strings are translated. I've tried everything i could:

- recreating my strings file,
- changing keys,

even putting working string & keys in not-working string but nothing is working.

All of my elements are UILabels and I've checked every single configuration for each of them. They all have the same configurations. It can be because of the project configuration but then why does some work? I have checked some other answers and tried the solutions (checking my keys, file name etc) but nothing is working. Please help me understand why is it happening.

EDIT:
Here's how I print my strings

```
//this one doesn't work
self.resolution.text = NSLocalizedString(@"RESOLUTION", nil);
//this one works
self.label1.text=NSLocalizedString(@"CAMERAS", nil);
```

And in my Localizable.strings file i have

```
"RESOLUTION"="Resolution";
"CAMERAS"="Cameras";
```

Comment: it has to work, looks clean to me. try to delete the app from the simulator, make a build clean and then run it again.

Comment: @holographix i just reset my simulator and now i can't compile my app. :s. Getting a "SIGABRT", I think I'll solve that prob now.

Comment: @holographix ok back again. And no it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soltuion to my problem was to delete app from simulator clean and build again as explained by holographix. Thanks holographix :)

What i still don't understand is that i tried the procedure many times and it didn't work and then just like that it decided to start working. Even though my problem is solved it's still a mystery to me.

Comment: This worked for me, but still, I don't want this to replicate on the app store.

Answer (score 1):

make another check, like inverting the order of the elements: try putting on the top on of the strings that does not figure out translated. then as a proof of concept try making a third localized file with non utf-8 chars (like in plain text with no frills)

Comment: already tried changing order of strings. Let's try it with the second part of your solution.

Comment: it may be an issue related to the utf-8 nature of the file.

Comment: i tried adding spanish localization. Same string are translated and the others not :s.

Comment: what i don't understand is why some of them work? I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: fail :( this is very awkward, this issue has never happened to me. and I make apps with 5 languages :-o

Comment: it's my first app and i got that, how unfair :p

Comment: I'm sorry for that, how many text fileds you got in your app?

Comment: I've 15 labels to translate. Can the number of elements create a problem like this?

Comment: nope, was just thinking about another issue, but this is not your case. can u provide a snippet of how you print one working label and a snippet of a non-working label?

Answer (score 1):

Coming back with Xcode 7. With one more trick.

I had the same problem but none of the above solutions did work (I'm not saying that it wouldn't work in other situations).

The solution was that I have a double **;** at the end of one definition (probably due to some cut,copy,paste operation). There was no compilation error or warning. I simply removed the redundant ; and that worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue. In my case, it was because the speech marks were different character codes in the *.strings file after copying the translation from Google translate. 
Reentering the speech marks fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your .strings file name to Localizable.strings, it worked for me.